# NameError: uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to learn the MVC structure of a site made in Rails. When I want to run

```
foreman start -f Procfile.noweb
```

it gives me this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions
```

These are the lines that appear to have the problem:

```
class CampaignDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  def_delegator :@view, :link_to
  def_delegator :@view, :edit_campaign_path
  include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari
```

Can you tell me what it means?

Comment: I means `AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions` doesn't exist. Did you define `AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions` somewhere? Perhaps a gem wasn't installed? Or a `require` is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my application.js file

```
//= require respond.min
//= require modernizr
//= require lodash/lodash
// require Placeholders.js
//= require underscore
// require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
// require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
// require DataTables/DataTables-1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables
// require DataTables/DataTables-1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap
// require DataTables/Buttons-1.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons
// require DataTables/Buttons-1.0.1/js/buttons.bootstrap
// require DataTables/Buttons-1.0.1/js/buttons.flash
// require DataTables/Buttons-1.0.1/js/buttons.html5
// require DataTables/Responsive-1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive
// require DataTables/Select-1.0.0/js/dataTables.select
//= require autonumeric
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
// require parsley
// require turbolinks
//= require twitter/typeahead

//= require jquery.noty.packaged
//= require hopscotch.js
// require bootstrap-tour
// require gritter
// require zeroclipboard
// require swfobject

//= require valorbit
//= require campaigns
//= require invitations
//= require twitterer
//= require ga
// require zendesk 
// require navbar
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require data-confirm-modal
```

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails', '~> 0.4.0'
gem "kaminari"
```

Comment: In requier it seems that 

// require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
// require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
// require DataTables/DataTables-1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables
// require DataTables/DataTables-1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap

does not have an equal in front of  the line. I think that it represent that it is not installed, or something like that. What can i have to do?